# Overloading the << operator in C++ -why return type is a reference std::ostream&

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm reading this [tutorial](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/9-2a-overloading-operators-using-normal-functions/) about overloading the `<<` operator in C++.

I'm trying to understand why the return type is a reference `std::ostream&`? The tutorial says that

> if you try to return std::ostream by value, you’ll get a compiler error. This happens because std::ostream specifically disallows being copied.

Could somebody explain whwere `std::ostream` is being copied?

```
   std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const Point &point)
{
    // Since operator<< is a friend of the Point class, we can access Point's members directly.
    out << "Point(" << point.m_x << ", " << point.m_y << ", " << point.m_z << ")";

    return out;
}
```

Comment: `return out;` that's where it'll get copied if you return by value. (Not taking into account NRVO and move semantics)

Comment: If you return it by value, it will get copied.

Comment: At a meta-level, the ostream object has identity, rather than value.  As an identity object, two different ostream objects are different.  Whereas with value objects, two objects of the same value are the same.  So returning the ostream object by reference is returning the same object, for the purpose of allowing the operations to chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, an object is copied when you:

1. define variables using an =
2. pass it as an argument to a parameter of nonreference type
3. return it from a function whose return type is nonreference
4. initialize an array or an aggregate class using braces

By the 3rd case, 'out' will be copied if the return type is `std::ostream`. So it should be `std::ostream&`. (You may notice that the type of the first parameter is also `std::ostream&`, avoiding copy)

Comment: I think 1. is in fact a subcase of 2. (It will call the copy constructor or assignement operator)

Comment: 3. and 4. also (they will call the copy constructor or assignement operator).